# Delphi: crypting resource file

Tags: delphi, encryption

I have this function that should crypt bytes from resource file but it's just crashing my app:

```
function crypt(src: Pointer; len: DWORD): DWORD;
var
  B: TByteArray absolute src;
  index: DWORD;
begin
  for index := 0 to len - 1 do
  begin
    B[index] := B[index] xor 5; //just to test if its working
  end;
  result := 1;
end;
```

i am using it like this:

```
hFind := FindResource(...);
size := SizeOfResource(HInstance, hFind);
hRes :=LoadResource(HInstance, hFind);
bytes :=LockResource(hRes);
crypt(bytes, size);
```

if i dont call the crypt function program works. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you want to *DEcrypt* the resource. Crypting the resource that way would be pointless, even if you make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code like this is easiest to write with pointers like this:

```
function crypt(src: Pointer; len: DWORD): DWORD;
var
  B: ^Byte;
  index: DWORD;
begin
  B := src;
  for index := 0 to len - 1 do
  begin
    B^ := B^ xor 5; //just to test if its working
    inc(B);
  end;
  result := 1;
end;
```

Naturally you do need to respect the issue of read-only memory that Sertac highlighted.  I'm just adding this code to illustrate what I believe to be the canonical way to walk a buffer that arrives as a void pointer.

Comment: I think Delphi's "void" pointers are usually called untyped or "naked".

Answer (score 4):

You've got two problems with that code. First is with the byte array, its elements do not contain your resource data but random data starting with the address of your pointer 'src'. Use a pointer to a TByteArray like this:

```
var
  B: PByteArray absolute src;              
  index: DWORD;
begin
  for index := 0 to len - 1 do
  begin
    B^[index] := B^[index] xor 5; //just to test if its working
  end;
  ..
```

Second is, you'll still get an AV for trying to modify a read-only memory segment. Depending on what you are trying to do, you can use `VirtualProtect` on 'bytes' before calling 'crypt', or copy the memory to a byte array and modify it there, or use `BeginUpdateResource`-`UpdateResource`-`EndUpdateResource` if you're trying to modify the resource.